# how to delete duplicate data from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Here i want to ask user to select which data he wants to delete

according to that i want to delete, but if the user selects data which is repeated then i want to select only duplicate.

so the problem is, i dont know when the user will select duplicate data and when it will select nonrepeated data

can any one help me ? I am new to mysql

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            String insert = "delete from photo where iname=" + "?";
            String image = "done.jpg";

            String insertQuery = "insert into photo (iname)" + "values" + "(?)";
            String query = "select * from photo";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "cubie", "mypass100");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {

                String sname = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(sname);

            }
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            pstmt.setString(1, image);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            st.executeUpdate("insert into photo values('principal.jpg')");
            st.executeUpdate("insert into photo values('done.jpg')");
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(insert);
            pstmt.setString(1, image);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reduce the code to the very core problem please. Don't just dump everything here.

Comment: as such there is no problem in my code i just want to add how i can delete duplicate data which i will accept from user

Comment: People don't want to read code that is not relevant. Please make your question short and concentrated to the facts. Otherwise people will just move along to the next question which they probably already have.

Comment: If it is irrelevant which entry will be deleted then just add a `limit 1` to the end of your delete query

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
String insertQuery="delete from photo where iname="+"?";
```

If you execute this statement you will delete all the rows with the given image name. If you have an ID column in your table you can rewrite your statement to delete first (or last) of your images. Something like this:

```
delete from photo where id = (select min(id) from photo where iname = ?)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'photo' for update in FROM clause
it gives error

Comment: try to find solution yourself. I've only showed you the way.